# How to calculate the probability of a set chosen containing a kind of special subset related to normal logic AND.

Tags: probability

Suppose random vector $X=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and  each $X_i $  i. i. d.$\sim $ Bernoulli distribution with $p=\frac{1}{2}$. That is $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.  All these $2^n$ random vectors forms a set $S$. Now the normal logic AND operation of two random vector $X, Y \in S$ as $$X\land Y=(X_1\land Y_1, X_2\land Y_2,\cdots, X_n \land Y_n)$$
Notice that $0\land 1=1\land 0=0 \land 0=0, 1\land 1=1$.

What we are interested is a kind of special subset of $S$, denoted by $D$, satisfying that  after doing the normal logic AND operation of all element of $D$, we get a random vector $(1,1,\cdots, 1,0,0,\cdots 0)$, the number of $1$ appeared is $k$, the number of $0$ is $n-k$. Now we random sample $m$ random vectors without replacement from $S$, to form a set $M$. Our question is how to use paramether $k, n, m$ to calculate the probability of $M$ containing such kind of sepcial subset $D$ ?